# ScrollView in android programming

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I used the scrollview in my xml file, but when I do this happen:

[image]

and the program refuse to run this app. ( pic 1 )

[image]

However, when I take out the code for scrollview it return to the normal form:

so what should I do to make scrollview work.

note: I put the scrollview code in the top of my code.

Comment: `the program refuse to run this app.`?

Comment: well i guess this is happeing because you are trying to put all these elements inside the scrollview and the scrollview is only hosting one child...so add the scrollview and then add linear layout as a child and then use them to create your form....the other thing is that when you try to put scroll view root element. put it inside the relative layout

Comment: Any error in logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ex :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="top">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```